# can a plasterboard ceiling hold a 4 kg projector

Tags: drywall, ceiling, carpentry

i want to mount a 4 kg projector in a plasterboard ceiling but can't find the joint so it will have to go in the plasterboard, i wanted to know if it will hold and what kind of things i'll need.
also if it will hold a 100" projector screen that is about 12 kg 
really need help with this.

Answer (score 1):

While I hate mounting things in ceilings without reaching joists (or other framing members), some modern [toggle type anchors](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hilti-1-4-in-HTB-Toggler-Bolts-with-Philips-Flat-Head-Screw-8-Pack-3512329/204992997) can hold loads of over 100 kg each in 1/2 inch drywall *per anchor* (many jurisdictions require 5/8 or thicker drywall in ceilings). 
[image: toggler]
The load on ceiling mounted items is *tensile* and the use of several mounting anchors should give you lots of room. [This link](http://www.toggler.com/products/snaptoggle/overview.php) shows the load ratings of one brand of toggle anchors. Brand to brand ratings may vary slightly.

I strongly prefer the rotating bar type toggles over the old spring-wing types. They allow installation and removal without losing the interior component, and the load seems to be better spread over the drywall surface.

While two or more toggle anchors are *theoretically* more than enough for a 12 kg screen, the ratings are for static tensile use. If the screen is being moved up and down, either mechanically or by hand, that is a dynamic load that multiplies the strain on the fitting.

There still should be enough room for normal use, but understand that someone pulling down with their whole weight on a screen is more than any such mounting bracket can sustain.

Finally, things falling from the ceiling can do *serious* harm. Make sure that the projector, and especially the screen, do not pose a risk to humans (we can live with broken ceilings and devices).

> *Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources*